# Firestore error limit_to_first, can't read firestore values

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to fetch the data from firestore, though it was working before but now it is stopped working and I am keep getting this error -

> [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(users/default/critical/home order by **name**);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

And my database Rules are defined like this -

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
                /*-----tile menus----------*/
        match /users/defaultmenuItems/{document=**} {
          allow read: if isOwner(userId); 
          allow write: if false;
        }

        match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
          allow read,write,update: if isOwner(userId); 
        } 

        function isOwner(userId) {
          return request.auth.uid == userId;
        }
    } 
}
```

Code performing the query in Android

```
public void readMenu(final String collection, final String path, final DataRead dataStatus) {
        firebaseFirestore.collection(collection)
                .document(userId + path)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                                dataStatus.DataIsRead(documentSnapshot);
                            } else {
                                getDeafaultItems(collection, path);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Sorry ....");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

private void getDeafaultItems(final String collection, final String path) {
        Log.d("MY_PATH",collection + "/defaultmenuItems"+path);
        firebaseFirestore.collection(collection)
                .document("defaultmenuItems" + path)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                            copyFromDefaults(collection, documentSnapshot, path);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

And Query is like this -

```
users/defaultmenuItems/critical/home
```

There was a mistake with **default** query which I have fixed with correct path as above. But the problem is still there.

Comment: Without seeing the code that's performing the query, there's not much we can do to help.  The query is obviously being rejected by some rule, but it's not possible to tell which one or how to resolve it.  Please edit the question with more details, and explain what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have added the code. Can you please  check?

Comment: There's still not enough information.  We can't see the values of the variables you're using in the query, so we don't know which collection or document you're trying to work with.  Hard code all the values so we can see what's going on.  Anyone should be able to take your code and reproduce the issue.

Comment: @BLΛCK, are you sure `request.auth.uid` has value `default`? Try changing `isOwner` to always return `true`. Will it work?

Comment: @DougStevenson I have updated my question. There was a mistake in my query but the problem is still there.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu yes there was a mistake in the query which I have fixed but the problem is still there.

Comment: Sorry guys I fixed it.

Comment: If you're done with the question, please delete it, or answer it with your solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule:

```
        match /users/defaultmenuItems/{document=**} {
          allow read: if isOwner(userId); 
          allow write: if false;
        }
```

is referring to a variable `userId` which simply does not exist here.  There is no wildcard with that name, so `userId` has no value.  It's not clear where you are expecting this value to come from, but you will need to rewrite this rule (or restructure your data) to more accurately express your security requirements.

Comment: yes I figured that out already. But thank you so much for help anyways :) :) be safe :)